# Lookup Table error: could not convert ‘ <brace-enclosed initializer list>’

Tags: c++, oop

I want to create class for Cars that is initialized by lookup table, but i have this error :  error: could not convert ‘{"Lambordgini Murcielago", 0, 670, 0}’ from ‘’ to ‘Cars’
 };

This is my source code:

```
class Cars
{
public:
enum Type
{
    Lambordgini = 0,
    Mercedes,
    Pagani,
    Bugatti,
    MAX_TYPES
};

Cars(Type type):m_name(carInfo[type].m_name),m_id_number(carInfo[type].m_id_number),
        m_hs_power(carInfo[type].m_hs_power), m_reg_number(carInfo[type].m_reg_number)
        {};

uint16_t getHorsePower() const;
uint16_t getIdNumber() const;
uint16_t getNumber() const;
const std::string& getName() const;

static Cars carInfo[MAX_TYPES];

private:

std::string m_name;
uint16_t m_id_number;
uint16_t m_hs_power;
uint16_t m_reg_number;
```

};

```
Cars Cars::carInfo[Cars::MAX_TYPES]
{
    {"Lambordgini Murcielago", 0, 670, 0000},
    {"Mercedes-AMG", 1, 503, 0000},
    {"Pagani Zonda R", 2, 740, 0000},
    {"Bugatti Veyron", 3, 1020,0000},
};
```

Comment: You are trying to use aggregate-initialization which in your case does not apply, since you have *a)* private members and *b)* a user-defined constructor. Hence you see the error.

Comment: @DeiDei You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: Normally, you could do this through [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).  However, that is disabled since you have private members and a user-defined constructor for the `Cars` class, so the format of your brace initializers must match that of your constructor, e.g. `Cars Cars::carInfo[Cars::MAX_TYPES] { {Type::Lambordgini}, ... }`.

Comment: Off-topic, but it looks a bit strange: "Lambordgini" -> "Lamborghini". ;-)